# Power Automate ODATA data Filter incorrect output (SQL Connector "Get Rows v2")

Tags: date, filter, odata, power-automate, between

I have a problem when querying an MS SQL DB using the Power Platform SQL Connector. In the ODATA filter I have specified a date range (in the example between 1/1/2024 and 1/31/2024) and yet I get a data record with "coverageDate" from 2/1/2024, how can that be?
[image]

The query works as desired via the SQL Manager.
(Unfortunately I can only use "Get Rows" in Power Automate, direct SQL query is not possible via OnPrem Gateway)

I thought that it might be due to some automatic "time zone calculation" in the background, so that the date in February is still in January, so to speak.

So I created three data sets with the following dates to test this:

- 12/31/2023 23:50
- 01/01/2024 06:00
- 02/01/2023 10:00

Only the middle data set should be present in the output. "12/31/2023 23:50" is not displayed in the output - so far ok. Due to the specified time and the problem mentioned, one might think that the middle data record (01/01/2024 06:00) would not be present in the output, but it is!

How can that be? I really have no idea what the problem is here.